# Getting Invalid library error when I am opening the workspace

Tags: powerbuilder

I created a new pbl in my current project and due to some reasons i deleted that library from the project.Now when I open my workspace,i am getting the error like 'Library ....pbl is invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the reference to the now deleted .pbl from the Library List of the target.   Rt click on the Target, choose Properties, then edit the library list.